# How do I reset my viewpoint back to normal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft 1.9.5pre let's you change the viewport with 'jkl' keys, and I've managed to distort the viewpoint on my game so much I have no idea how to get it back to normal.

How do I return my viewpoint back to normal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Controls), press <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> at the same time to reset the zoom, and press <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd> at the same time to reset the rotation.

BTW, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>i</kbd> won't mess your camera up; <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd> will.

Comment: For any who follow, if the FOV item in the video options menu is not standard, this can make this distorted effect much worse!